# Choose view model condtionally for items with different underlying types in a list, without explicitly checking and casting every item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic, viewmodel

I have a couple views with belonging view models, which are used in listings for specific content types on my site.

I want to reuse these view models when I list search results, where these content types are shown together in one listing.

I get the search result items as API items, 
I can then proceed to find the underlying type of the items and map them to the corresponding view model (DocumentViewModel for documents, NewsPageViewModel for news pages etc).

What I really would like to do is something like this:
        Map the search hit items to the correct view model for the underlying content        type. 
Then return the view models as dynamic objects together with a property that specifices their backing type, and a property for the view path/name.

```
    Model.dynamicItems =  new List<dynamic>()
    {document, newsPage};
    foreach(var item in Model.dynamicItems)
    {
            @{ Html.RenderPartial(item.viewName, (item.Type) item );}
    }
```

But as far as I know that's not possible, due to lack of duck typing.

I guess something like this could work, but it feels ugly and repetitive:

```
public Interface ISearchInterfaceItem
{
    string viewName {get; set;}
}

public class DocumentViewModel : ISearchInterfaceItem 
{
    ...
}

public class NewsPageViewModel : ISearchInterfaceItem 
{
    ... 
}


Model.SearchInterfaceItems =  new List<ISearchInterfaceItem>()
{newsPageItem, document};

foreach(var item in Model.SearchInterfaceItems)
{
    if(item as DocumentViewModel != null)
    {
        @{ Html.RenderPartial(item.viewName, (DocumentViewModel) item );}
    }

    else if (item as NewsPageViewModel != null)
    {
        @{ Html.RenderPartial(item.viewName, (NewsPageViewModel) item );}
    }
```

Are there any good ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world are you implementing interfaces if you're not going to use them? Just do:

```
foreach (ISearchInterfaceItem item in Model.SearchInterfaceItems)
```

(Then you don't even need to cast later on.)

Answer (score 0):

The good news is mvc has something simple for this.

-Create a EditorTemplates folder in your shared folder.

-create your partial views in this folder.

-The name of the view should be the name of the type it displays.

-In your view call EditorForModel helper method.

If you are not editing, you could also DisplayTemplates.